# LINQ Query to create Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have the following schema:

**ParentKey | Key | Value**

```
   1       A      3
   1       B      5
   1       C      6
   2       A      4
   2       D      8
```

I am getting this as an `IQueryable<MyObject>`

```
MyObject {
    public int ParentKey{get;set;}
    public String Key{get;set;}
    public int Value{get;set;}
}
```

I would like to turn this into a Dictionary of dictionaries where ParentKey is the key of the parent dictionary, and key is the key of child dictionary. I am currently doing this in loops, but I'd like to see how it can be done using LINQ.

I am guaranteed that the keys within a particular parent key will always be unique, so no need to worry about or check duplicates keys.

How can I write a LINQ query which will turn this data into a

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>
```

Comment: What type are you starting with?

Comment: @I3arnon I edited my post to reflect the data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to group the list by `ParentKey` first:

```
list.GroupBy(l => l.ParentKey)
    .AsEnumerable()     // to shift from IQueryable to IEnumerable and hydrate the results
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(gg => gg.Key, gg => gg.Value));
```

Comment: if the source is an IQueriable (as the question suggests) you would want to execute the first group by at the DB level and then do an AsEnumerable before ToDictionary. and a -1 bc. your second ToDictionary call will fail on duplicate keys

Comment: @AZ the OP specifically stated that there is *no need to worry about or check duplicates keys*

Comment: @AZ. It is an IQueryable, and I would like to turn this query into a ToDictionaryAsync, but his answer is valid because I mentioned that the keys are guaranteed to be unique for a given parent key.

Comment: my bad then. -1 removed. i still think an AsEnumerable before ToDictionary needs to placed in there.

Comment: @AZ `AsEnumerable()` added.